# How to make these custom hyperlinks jump to the start of the page instead of the exact hyper target?

Tags: hyperlink, hypertarget

I'm making a little pen and paper game with an index of items at its back. During the game, the player encounters items with instructions on where to find the item's details at the back of the document. However, when clicking these hyperlinks it takes me to the top of the item (and a little cut off too).

How do I alter these two commands so that when clicking the hyperlink, it takes the reader to the top of the page containing the item?

```
\newcommand{\makeitem}[1]{#1\hypertarget{#1}{}\label{#1}}


\newcommand{\gain}[1]{> \textbf{Gain:} \hyperlink{#1}{#1 (Page: \pageref*{#1})}}
```

Code example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\makeitem}[1]{#1\hypertarget{#1}{}\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\gain}[1]{> \textbf{Gain:} \hyperlink{#1}{#1 (Page: \pageref*{#1})}}

\begin{document}

On this page, the character picks up a torch:

\gain{Torch}

\newpage

And here would be the list of items including the torch:

\makeitem{Torch}

\newpage

Here is a third page so the doc has room to show what the scrolling actually looks like.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Re-welcome. Please, can you add a full minimal compilable code?

Answer (score 2):

targets (destinations in PDF speech) are not "locations" where a link jumps to. Instead they contain a page number and an instruction how to display this page.

By default the instruction tells the viewer to put a specific coordinate into the top-left corner -- which gives the impression that the link jumped to this place.

You can change the instruction by using (globally or locally when creating the target)

```
\hyperref{pdfview=...}
```

Possible values for your use are e.g. Fit or FitH.

This typically change the size of the page and is perhaps not what you want.
An alternative is to move the destination in the top-left corner of the page:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\makeitem}[1]{#1%
 \AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0pt,0pt){\hypertarget{#1}{}\label{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\gain}[1]{> \textbf{Gain:} \hyperlink{#1}{#1 (Page: \pageref*{#1})}}


\begin{document}

On this page, the character picks up a torch:

\gain{Torch} 
\newpage

And here would be the list of items including the torch:

\makeitem{Torch} 

\newpage

Here is a third page so the doc has room to show what the scrolling actually looks like.

\end{document}
```

A third alternative would be to make use of the page destinations hyperref creates anyway. This requires an expandable way to retrieve the page number:

```
\usepackage{zref-user}
\newcommand{\makeitem}[1]{#1\zlabel{#1}\label{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gain}[1]{> \textbf{Gain:} \hyperlink{page.\zref@extractdefault{#1}{page}{0}}{#1 (Page: \pageref*{#1})}}
\makeatother
```